# Proper way to detect and revive Quartz scheduler if it suddenly dies

Tags: java, wildfly, quartz-scheduler, restart

I have been using Quartz Scheduler in my Java Wildfly backend application for 2 years now (and before that in another project). I use it to trigger integrations with other systems on a minute/hourly/daily interval (reading values etc). In the past 2 months the integrations randomly stopped three times. It looks like Quartz randomly died. Logs don't show anything other than log entries from those integrations just stopping suddenly. While waiting for another occurrence to happen to do a ThreadDump, I really want to avoid data not being read on production environment. Is there any proper way to detect that Quartz has died and restarting it from within Wildfly server?

Comment: Instead of polling for health status you should try to understand why it fails.  This could help: https://nurkiewicz.com/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html

Comment: @Pino That is, of course, primary goal, but since it happens so rarely we cannot just wait until it happens again to do a thread dump and see what it can tell us. Quartz in my application fires multiple jobs every minute of every day that work ok (until the mentioned sudden stop every now and then), so it must be something tricky. Thank you for the article